# SecItemExport fails when exporting private key

Tags: macos, security, osx-lion, core-foundation

I would like to export a private ECDSA key using the new 10.7 `Security.framework` APIs but the operation keeps failing with error code -26260:

```
errSecPassphraseRequired     = -25260,  /* Passphrase is required for import/export. */
```

I would also like for the keys I generate not to be added to the keychain because they are for use on other machines and I will handle the storage myself.  Here is code that doesn't work- the first export succeeds, but the same key data once imported can't be exported again without a passphrase.  I haven't set a passphrase for this key. I've tried many combinations of export types, included wrapped OpenSSL and PEM armoring, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I have working code that does this already using OpenSSL, but since it is deprecated in Lion I wanted to see what the new APIs could do.

```
// Set up the parameters for 256-bit ECDSA
CFMutableDictionaryRef parameters = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeyTypeECDSA);
CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits, CFSTR("256")); // kSecp256r1
CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrIsPermanent, kCFBooleanFalse);

// Issue #1:
// SecKeyGeneratePair() adds the keys to the keychain, which I don't want to do
// The docs say that kSecAttrIsPermanent should change this behavior
SecKeyRef publicKey, privateKey;
OSStatus result = SecKeyGeneratePair((CFDictionaryRef)parameters, &publicKey, &privateKey);

CFRelease(parameters), parameters = nullptr;

if(noErr == result) {
    CFDataRef privateKeyData = nullptr;
    result = SecItemExport(privateKey, kSecFormatUnknown, 0, nullptr, &privateKeyData);
    if(noErr == result) {
        CFShow(privateKeyData);

        uint32_t format = kSecFormatUnknown;
        uint32_t itemType = kSecItemTypePrivateKey;
        CFArrayRef items = nullptr;
        result = SecItemImport(privateKeyData, nullptr, &format, &itemType, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &items);

        CFRelease(privateKeyData), privateKeyData = nullptr;
        CFRelease(privateKey), privateKey = nullptr;

        if(noErr == result) {
            privateKey = (SecKeyRef)CFRetain(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0));

            CFRelease(items), items = nullptr;

            // Issue #2:
            // SecItemExport() fails with -25260
            result = SecItemExport(privateKey, kSecFormatUnknown, 0, nullptr, &privateKeyData);
            if(noErr == result) {
                CFShow(privateKeyData);
                CFRelease(privateKeyData), privateKeyData = nullptr;
            }
            else
                printf("SecItemExport error: %d\n", result);
        }
        else
            puts("SecItemImport failed");
    }
    else
        printf("SecItemExport error: %d\n", result);
}
else
    printf("SecKeyGeneratePair error: %d\n", result);
```

Here is output from a sample run:

```
<CFData 0x10061b390 [0x7fff79ed3fa0]>{length = 121, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x307702010104209432679e712a4ac156 ... 219ffed31a54aff1}
SecItemExport error: -25260
```

Comment: Any joy with this? Also, fyi OpenSSL is only deprecated as a dynamic library provided by the OS. It's still ok to `brew install openssl` and then statically link or ship your own as a private dylib. I believe the reason for it being deprecated was just that the interface changed too much between releases.

Comment: I posted the same question on Apple's developer forums, and the consensus was that the fact that you can export a private key without a passphrase at all is a bug, and the automatic keychain addition is a bug as well.  I went ahead with OpenSSL since it is available, and if it is removed in 10.9 I'll worry about in a year.

Comment: -25260 is "A password is required for import or export." - U missed params in SecItemExport